# Many to Many to MorphToMany Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-query-builder

I have an **Exam**, **Question** and **Tag** (Spatie/laravel-tags package) models.

An `Exam` consists of many `Questions` (Many to Many), and `Question` has many `Tags` (MorphToMany).

I would like to have a method on the Exam model to get all the tags of Exam through its associated questions, such that `$exams→tags()` returns all the tags from associated questions belonging to the exam.

Can anyone point me towards what may be the best course to take in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have proper described relations, just write something like that:

```
// Exam Model

public function tags()
{
    return $this->questions->map(function($q){
        return $q->tags;
    })->collapse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the tags from exams like this

```
return Exam::with('questions.tags')->get();
```

If u want some conditions for tags you can do like this

```
return Exam::with(['questions.tags'=> function($query){
  $query->where('..','..')
}])->get();
```

If u want a proper function inside your model like you said just put the logic inside one function in. your model like this

```
Exam.php
public function getAllTags()
{
   return $this->with(['questions.tags'=> function($query){
     $query->select('..');
   }])->get();
}
// This will just give you what you need
```

Let me know if this helps