# Laravel Nested Relationship Get List of Ids in Column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have encounter a problem that I am not able to solve :/

So, I currently have 4 Models: Make > Model > Generation > Version(['engine_type'])

I need to get a unique list of all the fuels (engine_type) that a certain car model has within it's versions. i.e: for $model = Model::find(1) I want all of it's $model->generations()->versions()->get('engine_type') as a list of unique ids so I can know which engine types this car models has!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/61658193/7155723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first step: you should get all generations for the current model, that would be achieved by join table 'models' with table 'generations' ....

second step: join the results with the table 'versions' witch contain the result column we desire to show ('engine_type')
this chain of join should use the foreign keys that represent relations between the tables, so you have to make sure that you setup up your relation well ...

third step: after selecting 'versions.engine_type' use 'distinct()' to make sure there is no duplicate result,
more about distinct in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#selects

```
$ids= Model::where('id',$modelId)->join('generations','generations.model_id','models.id')
->join('versions','versions.generation_id','generations.id')
->select('versions.engine_type')->distinct()->get();
```

Comment: @OMR one quick follow up, right now it is returning the models, I want only an array with the ids like => [1, 2] how could I do it?

Comment: you can use ->all() to make the result as array

Comment: @JeremyCaney Yes, for an expert or relative experienced coder, it might be an answer but as you might as well know, documenting code with helpful explanation helps our community and new enthusiastic programmers.

Comment: @iankits: This is fixed now so it’s no longer relevant, but it’s worth noting that code-only answers, while discouraged, [are still considered answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)—assuming, of course, that they’re otherwise on topic. Your first comment was fine (and I upvoted it) but the answer shouldn’t have been voted for deletion. That said, I wholeheartedly agree that code-only answers don’t otherwise fulfill the promise of Stack Overflow to help educate new and enthusiastic programmers.

Comment: Also, thank you @omr for updating your answer. This is a big improvement.